# FILE pointer acts different as a function parameter in C

Tags: pass-by-value, pointer-to-member, ansi-c

In the following code I created a char pointer and a FILE pointer, and tried to pass both to a function "by value of course".

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void move(char *s){
    ++s;
}
void moveF(FILE *f){
    getc(f);
}
int main(){
    char *s = malloc(64);
    strcpy(s,"123456");
    puts(s);
    move(s);
    puts(s);

    //~~~~~~~~~~
    FILE *f = fopen("file1","r");
    printf("%d\n",(int)ftell(f));
    moveF(f);
    printf("%d\n",(int)ftell(f));
}
```

I know that passing by value means that the parameter is a copy of the original variable in the calling function, That's why you can notice that after passing the char pointer, it's value in main function was not changed at all, but what is weird is that passing a FILE pointer and changing the value of the parameter caused changing the value of the variable inside main function.

Can someone please explain this behavior.
Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. `getc` will modify the "current" position in the FILE stream that `f` points to. That is the only thing you have demonstrated here, and that is correct behavior.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman so it's different in the case of a file stream, there is an indicator to some position in the stream and all copies of pointers will point to the same position and any modification will affect this indicator, thug affecting all other pointers values right ??

Answer (score 0):

Passing a pointer to an object is the same as passing the object by reference.  Hence, you’re passing a `FILE` structure by reference.  The pointers in either function point to the same object in memory, so either can modify the object and see the others changes.

Comment: While true, it's maybe missing the point a bit, because the observed behavior is about an *input stream*, not a `FILE` object associated to it.

Comment: @Hurkyl You can modify that through the pointer, too.  Basically, a `FILE*` is mostly used like a file handle. Any part of the program with a copy of it can perform operations on the stream that change its state.